# Arduino with ESP8266 via serial pass through

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, esp8266

I bought an Arduino Mega 2650 alongside a couple of ESP8266 chips hoping to make a wireless project take off.

Using the basic serial passthrough code

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial1.begin(115200);
    Serial.write("Starting");
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {      // If anything comes in Serial (USB),
       Serial1.write(Serial.read());   // read it and send it out Serial1 (pins 0 & 1)
    }

    if (Serial1.available()) {     // If anything comes in Serial1 (pins 0 & 1)
       Serial.write(Serial1.read());   // read it and send it out Serial (USB)
    }
}
```

updated to use a 115200 baud rate which it seems my version of the 8266 is programmed to use, I encounter this problem when trying to issue it commands:

```
Starting
AT

ERROR
```

[Looking around](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-ESP8266-give-error-message-on-AT-command) [I found](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21172/esp8266-01-at-commands-returns-random-chars-and-or-error) that this could be caused by the chip not getting enough power. So I hooked it up to a small power breakout board [image: breakout board]
 with a small 12 power supply I used to have connected to something else. After doing that all it does is spit out question marks even when I dont send anything. Weird part is the TX pin on the arduino thats going crazy? As if I am sending it to myself without a prompt from the ESP board. This only happens when I'm connected to that breakout supply.

[image: nothing]

Other oddity:
If I have all my wires except for VCC/CH_PD connected everything is fine, but the second I connect them to that power supply everything goes crazy and my TX pin starts flashing up a storm (can it be a voltage issue that also transfers to my Arduino board as well?)

Comment: set `Both NL & CR` line ending in one of the Serial Monitor comboboxes

Comment: Many questions are open here: Are you *sure* the baud rate of the ESP8266 is 115200? Show us the code or firmware running on it please? Where are the voltage divider resistors to protect the ESP8266 receiving 5V from the Arduino Mega's UART TX line? What does is show when you read the ESP8266 serial to 74880, which is the baud rate of the first-stage bootloader?

Comment: You are also making the mistake of reading from serial at 115200 baud and sending it to the other at a much lower 9600 baud. When the ESP8266 will send a stream of data and you write it byte-wise to the 9600 serial, it takes too much time for writing it, and you will loose incoming data. You must set the serial you're outputting to at least as high or higher than its input.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt From power supply to VCC and from Arduino TX to ESP RX I have a 1/2kohm voltage divider to turn 5v -> ~3.3v. I've tried every baud rate now, and the only one that gave me anything other than question marks was 115200. I havent touched the code or firmware, I cant even establish a serial connection to start looking into that.

Comment: @Juraj Yeah the blue light isn't even active on the ESP module anymore so its like is not getting a signal

Comment: it replays with ERROR, so it is alive. do you have the line ending characters set?

Comment: @Juraj It will now print `ok` in response to the `AT` command but any other command from this list returns an error https://nurdspace.nl/ESP8266#AT_Commands

Comment: Was using the wrong commands, please write an answer and I will mark it as correct :)

Comment: But you didnt get marked as the answer for that one either, it would be good to have one marked as solved (and without -2 votes)

Comment: @Juraj - The OP did not use the `@` symbol before your username, so you may not have seen their comment. They said "Was using the wrong commands, please write an answer and I will mark it as correct :)".

Comment: @VE7JRO, OP meant line endings not commands so I linked it to duplicate